# How can I access the object that called the method of its class within the same method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

```
    public class Container : XmlElementGenerator
{
    public string projectcode { get; set; }
    public string projectname { get; set; }
    public string projectleader { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string sampleartid { get; set; }
    public string sampledescription { get; set; }
    public string remark { get; set; }
    public DateTime samplingdate { get; set; }
    public int samplenumber { get; set; }

    public XmlElement GenerateXMLElement(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        Type containerGenerator = typeof(Container);

        XmlElement container = ElementChildrenGenerator(xmlDocument, "container");

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in containerGenerator.GetProperties())
        {
            container.AppendChild(ElementChildrenGenerator(xmlDocument, prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this).ToString()));
        }

        return container;
    }

}
```

Here an error on `prop.GetValue(this)` - "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Why I cant use "this" to access the object? I do not want to add one more parameter. Pls help

Comment: Are you certain this is the full code? The name "ContainerGenerator " indicats that this is a static class. If so there can be no instances you could call.

Comment: @Christopher Nope. I'm just having problems with the naming of classes. :D That is the usual class, I want get values from the object to generate xml document

Comment: @Christopher ElementChildrenGenerator is an inherited method. Maybe this is the problem in it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @stickybit , that error:"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Sound like the underlying property and therefore `prop.GetValue(this)` is `null`. You can't call `ToString()`on `null` (without an exception, that is). (How) do you want to a `null` as child (e.g. empty string or just don't add it)? Either coalesce it like `(prop.GetValue(this) ?? "").ToString()` or add and `object o = prop.GetValue(this); if (object != null) { ...` or whatever handling you come up with.

Comment: i believe this line is where your issue is  Type containerGenerator = typeof(Container);  you might try changing to Type containerGenerator= typeof(this);

Comment: @stickybit I set the breakpoints and looked at the state of the object, and it's not null

Comment: I meant the return value of `prop.GetValue(this)` maybe is null, not `this`(obviously). Just to clarify that.

Comment: What's the error message because there I really don't see why you're not able to do it that way.  It would be more helpful for us to know what the error message is saying.

Comment: @stickybit Dammit, your rigth

Comment: *Why I cant use "this" to access the object*...of course you can. Why are you saying you cannot; do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Container : XmlElementGenerator
{
    public string projectcode { get; set; }
    public string projectname { get; set; }
    public string projectleader { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string sampleartid { get; set; }
    public string sampledescription { get; set; }
    public string remark { get; set; }
    public DateTime samplingdate { get; set; }
    public int samplenumber { get; set; }

    public XmlElement GenerateXMLElement(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
       XmlElement container = ElementChildrenGenerator(xmlDocument,"container");

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            container.AppendChild(ElementChildrenGenerator(xmlDocument, prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this).ToString()));
        }

        return container;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - I just did not check null value input to the properties. Did the check and it worked.